# change default size of IMG tag with CSS

Tags: html, image, css

A have simple image tag with wrong URL

http://jsbin.com/monivava/1/edit

```
<img  src="http://placekitten!!!.com/g/200/200">
```

The problem is that default size for this failed image is 18x20 ( at least at webkit ), but i want it to be 0px so if image is failed to load then it would take zero space.

**Is there a way I can do that with CSS/HTML only?**

**UPD:**

I don't have any CSS width/height or HTML attribute width/height ( see example above )

**UPD2:**

I know that i can do that with JS, but i have explicitly said that i'm searching for CSS/HTML only solution.

**UPD3:**

I want to change default size ONLY for the image that failed to load. So if image is failed to load have size of 0px, and if it's loaded 100px ( for example )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `CSS` in **Mozilla Firefox**. Use this:

```
img:-moz-broken:not([height]), img:-moz-user-disabled:not([height]) {
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
}
```

You could also use `display: none;` to hide the broken image, but that's all up to you.

**In `webkit` browsers (like *Chrome, Safari*), however, there is no such thing to hide or change it if it is broken and you want to use `CSS` only**. You should use `jQuery` for that one.

Edit:

If you want it specifically for that image, you can use:

```
<img src="http://placekitten!!!.com/g/200/200" height="12" width="12">
```

My last edit:

```
 $("img").error(function(){
      $(this).hide();
    });
```

This is from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/error/). Should be enough for Webkit.

Comment: Wow o_O Tnx, it's working as magic. But i can't ignore WebKit ( unfortunately ), i even can't ignore IE :) So it's look like i'm forced to use JS.. tt..

Comment: with js you can just use something like `<img src="xyz" onerror="'this.style.display = "none"'/>`

Comment: I want to specify size ONLY for image that failed to load.

Comment: Check my edited answer. I have stated the `jQuery`, `CSS` and `HTML` solution. You owe me a cup of coffee mister!

Comment: -.- tnx a lot. But it's really bad that in the "era of HTML5" we can't  do that in CSS. It's kind of an absurd.

Comment: Don't blame me, blame the Google Chrome and Safari users who are stubborn not to use the best browser in the market (so yeah, Firefox rocks). PS: mark the answer as answered so we can close this topic off.

Comment: Not blaming u. Just making my statement. Firefox rocks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok since all other answers suggest JS, which you don't want to use there's one alternative i can think of.

But it's not recommend for content images, actually.

Anyhow, if you want to do it crossbrowser compatible (and not only for firefox like the good answer above) you have to use a div, set it's background to transparent and your image.

```
<div id="myImage">
    <img src="http://placekitten!!!.com/g/200/200"/>
</div>

<style>
    #myImage {
        background: transparent url('http://placekitten!!!.com/g/200/200') no-repeat;
    }

    #myImage img {
        display: none
    }
</style>
```

Comment: the problem is that the image size will be the same for Image that loaded and Image that failed to load. I want to change default size ONLY for the image that failed to load. So if image is failed to load have size of 0px, and if it's loaded 100px ( for example )

Comment: well I see the problem here http://jsbin.com/liyecice/1/edit it works 'visually' but the problem is that in your solution image still takes size. I really need size of a 0 for failed image ( so it would not take place )

Comment: see, now i didn't think. with `display:none` the image has no width and height anymore, what we actually wanted if it gets loaded. feel free to downvote, cause im out of ideas right now and this didnt solve it for you. maybe im getting back at this later the day.

Comment: np. Tnx for trying, i appreciate that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should either set the CSS to `auto` ->

```
img {
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

Or don't define both height and width at all. By doing so, it takes the size of the image that is loaded as the size (or the parents div). If there is no image, thus no size information, there is no space taken.

Comment: plz look at the example http://jsbin.com/monivava/1/edit i don't have any width and height in my css

Comment: i wonder who upvoted your answer...you clearly didnt even read the question thoroughly..he wants to hide the image if it fails to load...of course theres no image. he doesnt want to see the "broken-image"-icon...

Comment: I have up-voted his answer. I just really have 'down-voting' as a system. You can hit me if you want, i just don't think we should punish people for not 'not paying attention', 'not noticing' or 'not knowing'... sry, but that's the way I am :/

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it with query

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($("ImgID").attr('src')=="IMAGEFAIL/EXTENSION"){

    this.width("0");
    this.height("0");

    //instead you can use this.hide()

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revove the img if it failed to load with javascript like this:

```
<img  src="http://placekitten!!!.com/g/200/200" onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)" >
```